Python Execution Script manager with Web Interface?
So I have a Python Django project which uses Celery as well as Flower
To launch all the three processes I need to start them on three different terminals with the commands:
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080

celery -A Lab worker -l info --concurrency 3

celery --broker=redis://172.20.1.2:6379/0 flower --port=5566

I was looking for a simpler solution, some sort of graphic interface where I have all these three commands already registered and I have just to click "launch".
If I want to kill the process, maybe a "stop" button would be cool as well
I'm looking something like Portainer is for Docker
I've seen Spotify has created something for amnage Python scripts called Luigi, but I'm not sure if it fits my needs
